# Get the name of an image taken from camera/photo library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am having an issue with getting the name of an image that is taken from the photo library or camera. I have successfully picked the image but I want to send the picked image as an email attachment using MFMailComposeViewController. The problem is that the MFMailComposeViewController required a specific name of the image. I have used the following code to get the image name, and it always returning "assest.JPG" and that is not working with MFMailComposeViewController

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
[imageView setImage:image];
image_ = image;
image_ = [UIImage imageNamed:@"file.jpg"];
NSURL *imagePath = [editingInfo objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
imageName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];

NSLog(@"%@",imageName);
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
if (CAMORLIB == 1) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}}
```

is there is any other way to deal with this issue?

Thanks,

Mohammed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code here:

```
image_ = image;
image_ = [UIImage imageNamed:@"file.jpg"];
```

doesn't make sense, as it assigns to `image_` twice.  The `UIImage` method `-imageNamed:(NSString*)name` tries to load a file named `file.jpg` from disk.

The reason your `MFMailComposeViewController` doesn't work is that the above code results in `image_` being `nil` because `[UIImage imageNamed:@"filename"]` doesn't find a file named that (and as a result returns `nil`)

### Attaching to mail

When attaching an image to a MFMailComposeViewController, you tell it what filename you want the image to have, along with the image's data:

```
NSData* myData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .70f);
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"desiredfilename.jpg"];
```

Here, `image` is a `UIImage` and `@"desiredfilename.jpg"` is the filename you want the image to appear to have in the email.

Comment: StackOverflow custom is to upvote or accept helpful answers.  When you build a history of providing this feedback on answers, your questions will be answered more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling an image from the Assets Library only gives you the guid url of the item.

There is no real construct of names in the Assets Library. The photo library has a few properties but they are as follows

```
ALAssetPropertyType
ALAssetPropertyLocation
ALAssetPropertyDuration
ALAssetPropertyOrientation
ALAssetPropertyDate
```

all of which can be found in `AssetsLibrary.framework\ALAsset.h`

to put a name for images I gather from there, I usually put

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:"Image%@.png",imageNumber]
```

where image number incremented as I add images.

Hope that helps